# How to make these boxes?

Tags: graphics, formatting, diagrams, boxes, automation

I don't know how exactly to call what I want to implement. It's like a box surrounded with a line and, depending on the context, I want to place a graphic on the right corner e.g. a light bulb or a question mark.

I want to place these boxes in more than one place, so if there's a link explaining how to automate these things - a macro I guess - that would be appreciated too.

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Update

After new requirement in comments, now theres just one environment `coolbox` with a mandatory argument (the file image to be used) and two optional ones:

```
\begin{coolbox}[<options for the box>]{<image-file>}[<options for the image>]
(contents)
\end{coolbox}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{boxbg}{RGB}{179,222,255}

\tcbset{
  common/.style={
    before=\vskip2\baselineskip\noindent,
    after=\vskip2\baselineskip,
    enhanced,
    frame code={},
    fontupper=\LARGE,
    fontlower=\LARGE,
    segmentation empty,
    middle=0.7cm,
    top=0.5cm
  }
}

\DeclareTColorBox{coolbox}{O{}mO{}}{
common,
interior code={
  \filldraw[ultra thick,densely dashed,fill=boxbg,draw=black,rounded corners=10pt,#1] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
  \node at  ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=5pt]interior.north east) {\includegraphics[#3]{#2}};
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{coolbox}{lightbulb}[height=2cm]
Did you know:
\tcblower
Once upon a time there was a latch \\
that wanted to be a flip-flop?
\end{coolbox}

\begin{coolbox}{questionmark}[width=1cm,angle=-20]
Did you know:
\tcblower
Once upon a time there was a latch \\
that wanted to be a flip-flop?
\end{coolbox}

\begin{coolbox}[fill=red!20,draw=red]{exclamationmark}[width=1.5cm,angle=-20]
Did you know that adding some more text
\tcblower
Once upon a time there was a latch \\
that wanted to be a flip-flop?
\end{coolbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox); adjust the settings according to your needs:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{boxbg}{RGB}{179,222,255}

\tcbset{
  common/.style={
    before=\vskip2\baselineskip\noindent,
    after=\vskip2\baselineskip,
    enhanced,
    colback=boxbg,
    frame code={},
    fontupper=\LARGE,
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{ideabox}{
common,
interior code={
  \filldraw[ultra thick,densely dashed,fill=boxbg,draw=black,rounded corners=10pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
  \node at  ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=5pt]interior.north east) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{lightbulb}};
  }
}
\newtcolorbox{questionbox}{
common,
interior code={
  \filldraw[ultra thick,densely dashed,fill=boxbg,draw=black,rounded corners=10pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
  \node at  ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=5pt]interior.north east) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,angle=-30]{questionmark}};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ideabox}
Did you know:\par\vskip1cm

Once upon a time there was a latch \\
that wanted to be a flip-flop?
\end{ideabox}

\begin{questionbox}
Did you know:\par\vskip1cm

Once upon a time there was a latch \\
that wanted to be a flip-flop?
\end{questionbox}

\end{document}
```

If all the boxes are going to have this structure (i.e., an upper and a lower part), then (as **cmhughes** suggests in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269851/how-to-make-these-boxes/269864#comment648124_269864)) one can use `\tcblower` and `middle` to avoid manually producing the vertical separation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{boxbg}{RGB}{179,222,255}

\tcbset{
  common/.style={
    before=\vskip2\baselineskip\noindent,
    after=\vskip2\baselineskip,
    enhanced,
    colback=boxbg,
    frame code={},
    fontupper=\LARGE,
    fontlower=\LARGE,
    segmentation empty,
    middle=0.7cm
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{ideabox}{
common,
interior code={
  \filldraw[ultra thick,densely dashed,fill=boxbg,draw=black,rounded corners=10pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
  \node at  ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=5pt]interior.north east) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{lightbulb}};
  }
}
\newtcolorbox{questionbox}{
common,
interior code={
  \filldraw[ultra thick,densely dashed,fill=boxbg,draw=black,rounded corners=10pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
  \node at  ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=5pt]interior.north east) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,angle=-30]{questionmark}};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ideabox}
Did you know:
\tcblower
Once upon a time there was a latch \\
that wanted to be a flip-flop?
\end{ideabox}

\begin{questionbox}
Did you know:
\tcblower
Once upon a time there was a latch \\
that wanted to be a flip-flop?
\end{questionbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, but when I run it it doesn't compile (no dashed lines and no image, I use images with the same name ofc). I get these warnings too:

Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 40--40

Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 47--47

Comment: @user2692669 To help diagnose the problem, please copy the *exact* code I posted in a new document (no copy-paste into an already existing document, but in a fresh new document with just the code I posted) and compile it. What do you get? Any error messages? If so, which ones?

Comment: That's what I did, I compiled it with XeLaTex (if that is a matter). What format are the images that you use?

Comment: @user2692669 I just did a test with XeLaTeX and everythink was OK. The images I use are in PNG format. Did you get any errors with my code or simply got no boxes at all without errors?

Comment: This is exactly what I got: http://i.imgur.com/lu0syZo.png?1

Comment: @user2692669 I see that you are using an outdated TeX Live2013. That might be the problem. What happens if you use pdflatex instead of xelatex?

Comment: Same thing, I think my installation must be corrupted (I opened tex live manager and it crashed). I got the same results over at linux (version of latex is the same because I installed it about the same time there too). I'm reinstalling tex live in windows, maybe it will fix it.

Comment: Update: problem fixed, I still get the "overfull \hbox" warning (no edits done to the original text), should I be concerned?

Comment: @user2692669 Glad to hear the problem's solved. Regarding the overfull boxes, I had forgotten a `\noindent` in the `before` part, that I've added in my updated answer. This should fix the problem. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Perfect! I don't understand why that happened but it's gone now. Answer accepted!

Comment: +1 :) instead of the `\par\vskip1cm` could you do something with `tcbupper`? just curious :)

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks. Sure. But since I wasn't sure about the real use of the box (it's not clear if in every use it's going to be this kind of separation) I decided not to use `tcbupper`. Perhaps I'll add a variation with `tcbupper` later.

Comment: @cmhughes Answer updated using `\tcblower`.

Comment: Awesome work, as always :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I noticed that if I want to use larger text it runs through the image :/ . Also, is there a way to parameterize the image source so isntead of having 1-2 fixed types of boxes, I use a different image every time? Thank you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Perhaps, the boxes should get an optional argument in order to change parameters for particular boxes? At the moment, everything is quite fixed, apart from setting it with `\tcbset`

Comment: @user2692669 Please see my updated answer. You can have now as many boxes as you want.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer After request from the OP, this has changed in the updated answer.

Comment: Very nice! (As I understand it's a tradeoff between the image's size and the space we leave under the image so it doesn't touch the text)

Comment: @user2692669 Yes. You can change the `top` value to suit your needs. Or move the image a little upwards changing the `yshift=5pt` shift I used in the node for the image.

Answer (score 24):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}                   
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{skyblue}{HTML}{B9E1FD}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt, inner sep=7pt]
  \node [draw,rounded corners,dashed,fill=skyblue,text width=.6\textwidth] (B){%
  \bfseries Did you know? \par \bigskip  
  Once upon a time there was a latch that wanted to be a flip.flop};
  \node [rotate=-30]at($(B.north)!.65!(B.north east)$) {\includegraphics[scale=.09]{bulb}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

`TikZ` can also be used to produce such fancy boxes. The width can be adjusted as required (I used `.65\textwidth` here). Also the color is your choice (I used `{HTML}{B9E1FD}` here).

Finally, the lightbulb image can be downloaded from [this site](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/incandescent-light-bulb_69172).

[image]

Now the question block is obtained the same way as above with the last line changed to:

```
\node at ($(B.north)!.72!(B.north east)$) {\includegraphics{quest}};
```

Again, the question mark image was obtained [from here](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/question-mark_36601).